# How to show profile details only in career sections?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

I wanted to create a profile in the Stack Overflow careers section, but I am worried about my colleagues as they are active on Stack Overflow. I do not want to let my colleagues know that I am eagerly waiting for a job change. If I make a profile in careers, then my colleagues may come to know that I am in search for a job change and this way my employer will be notified.

Is there a way to show the careers section only to those employers to whom I apply on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Sure, you can hide the Jobs stuff from your Stack Overflow profile, if you choose. But they can probably still find you if they're really motivated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to show the careers section only to those employers to whom I apply on Stack Overflow?

Yes, we've set up some privacy settings so you can have a Developer Story that is visible only to employers if you're interested in job opportunities.

First, [go to your Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2664200/). If you hover over the top section (where your name is), you'll see an edit option. In this section, you are presented with 2 choices:

- Display Name - How you appear to other users on the Stack Overflow Q&A Network
- Real Name - How you appear to employers and other users when you share your Developer Story

You can keep your Stack Overflow username in the Display Name, then if you make your Developer Story visible your username will appear not your real name.  Your real name would only be shown to employers and others when you share your Developer Story via a public link.

Second, you can update the settings in your profile. By going to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) > Edit Profile & Settings > Developer Story Preferences you have a few options.

- Under Privacy, you can uncheck the box which means no one except for you and for employers who you have expressed interest in, will be able to see your Developer Story.
- You can get your public URL links that would be used to share your Developer Story.

The final thing you could do is go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) > Edit Profile & Settings > Job Match Preferences and update your Job Search Status. Your Developer Story is only visible to employers if you have expressed interest in being contacted.

All of these were put in place, so you can control who get to see your Developer Story and when you're interested in jobs.